How can I extract which Python lines are used when running a Python script, including the Python lines of the libs it's using?
Example: I have this Python script SE_Q_coverage.py:
# pip install transformers
from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('huawei-noah/TinyBERT_General_4L_312D')
if False:
    print('this line is not hit')
tokenized_inputs = tokenizer('hello world !'.split(' '),
                             is_split_into_words=True, return_tensors="pt")
print(tokenized_inputs)

How can I automatically or semi-automatically extract which Python lines are used when running this Python script?

I am aware of coverage.py, but it only shows which lines in SE_Q_coverage.py are used when running this Python script. It does not show which lines in SE_Q_coverage.py are used in the transformers lib. Example:
pip install coverage
coverage html SE_Q_coverage.py

outputs:


I am also aware of trace, but it outputs each line executed, including lines in any used library (here, transformers and possibly libs that transformers itself uses).
python -m trace --trace .\SE_Q_coverage.py > trace.txt

outputs a 50+MB log file:
--- modulename: SE_Q_coverage, funcname: <module>
SE_Q_coverage.py(2): from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer
 --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _find_and_load
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1170): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1171): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1173):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __init__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(166): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(167):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __enter__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(170):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _get_module_lock
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(185): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(186): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(187): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(188): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(189): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(190): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(192): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(193): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(196):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __init__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(72): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(73): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(74): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(75): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(76): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(77): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(198): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(209): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(211): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(213): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(171):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: acquire
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(106): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(107): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(108): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(109): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(110): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(111): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(112): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(113): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(114): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(110): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(123): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1174): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1175): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1176):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _find_and_load_unlocked
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1121): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1122): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1123): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1124): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1138):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _find_spec
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1056): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1057): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1062): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1068): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1069): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1070):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __enter__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1028): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1071): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1072): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1078):  --- modulename: __init__, funcname: find_spec
__init__.py(92):         if path is not None and not fullname.startswith('test.'):
__init__.py(95):         method_name = 'spec_for_{fullname}'.format(**locals())
__init__.py(96):         method = getattr(self, method_name, lambda: None)
__init__.py(97):         return method()
 --- modulename: __init__, funcname: <lambda>
__init__.py(96):         method = getattr(self, method_name, lambda: None)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1070):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __exit__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1032): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1069): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1070):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __enter__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1028): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1071): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1072): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1078):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: find_spec
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(750): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(753): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1070):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __exit__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1032): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1069): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1070):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __enter__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1028): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1071): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1072): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1078):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: find_spec
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(922):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _call_with_frames_removed
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(923): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(924): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1070):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __exit__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1032): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1069): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1070):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __enter__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1028): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1071): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1072): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1078):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: find_spec
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1502): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1503): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1504):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _get_spec
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1469): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1470): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1471): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1473):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _path_importer_cache
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1429): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1436): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1437): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1438): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1439):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _path_hooks
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1411): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1413): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1414): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1415):  --- modulename: zipimport, funcname: __init__
<frozen zipimport>(65): <frozen zipimport>(67): <frozen zipimport>(69): <frozen zipimport>(70): <frozen zipimport>(72): <frozen zipimport>(73): <frozen zipimport>(74): <frozen zipimport>(75):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _path_stat
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(147): <frozen zipimport>(86): <frozen zipimport>(88): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1416): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1417): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1413): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1414): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1415):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: path_hook_for_FileFinder
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1698):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _path_isdir
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(166): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(168):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _path_is_mode_type
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(152): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(153):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _path_stat
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(147): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(156): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1700):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: __init__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1563): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1564): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1564): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1564): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <genexpr>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1565): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1564): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1566): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1568): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1569): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1574): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1575): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1576): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1440): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1441): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1474): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1475): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1476):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: find_spec
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1609): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1610): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1611): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1612):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _path_stat
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(147): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1615): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1616):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: _fill_cache
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1657): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1658): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1659): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1666): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1674): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1680): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1676): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1677): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1678): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1681): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1675): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1682): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1683): <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1684):  --- modulename: _bootstrap_external, funcname: <setcomp>
[...]

Instead, I would like to see which lines are hit in \Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\tokenization_auto.py and other files in the transformers lib.

There is no way to answer the question "what lines are hit" for any program that is not entirely determined by the code. If the code does anything like reading user input, a file, a random generator, etc., the outcome cannot be known and the code reached neither. You could say you want all possibly reached lines given the code and any input, but that basically amounts to determining what lines are unreachable. Your title suggests you don't only want this analysis for your code, but for the full standard library and installed libraries as well - why do you need this? What's the actual problem?

@Grismar Thanks, assume that there is no user input and no a random generator. Only a predetermined file is read. Actual problem: To make a easier for someone else to port in C++. Also, it'd be convenient for myself to more easily see how it works. (these 2 points are quite similar).

"Only a predetermined file is read" - which is not code, and cannot be included in static analysis, and thus the question becomes unanswerable. If you just want to see how the code works, stepping through it in an interactive debugger would probably be the best (and common) approach. If porting the code to C++ would involve porting all involved library code as well, you're probably making a very bad port. A better approach would be to analyse what the code achieves, not what lines of Python make it up. Also note that the assumption you're asking us to make is not one such a tool could make.

@Grismar thanks, how about a dynamic analysis like trace or coverage, but unlike coverage, also showing lines in transformers instead of only SE_Q_coverage.py (and being less verbose than trace)?

Just run coverage html without the argument, and it'll format all of the data that is in the .coverage data file..?

@AKX thanks, how to generate the .coverage data file so that it includes lines used in transformers lib?

coverage run --include '*' example.py

will include absolutely everything in coverage reporting (don't mind the already-imported warnings).
Then,
coverage report

will show you everything, as will the HTML written by
coverage html

If you're only interested in transformers, you could try
coverage run --include '**/transformers/**' example.py

(strange syntax since the transformers directory is not in the current path, etc. etc.).

Works great, thanks very much!

@FranckDernoncourt Glad I could help. Please remember to also accept the answer.
